# TRIGGER to update related records on Junction object

Tags: apex, trigger, junction-object

My scenario is One candidate can have a multiple Job application, custom objects are

1. candidate__c(lookup to job application)
2. Job_Openings__c(lookup to Job application)
3. Job_Applications__c(junction Object)

whenever a candidate is created, job application created manually. A candidate can have two or more job applications.

let us take example

candidate A1

job opening java, javascript, and apex

job application 1 is created for A1 with java

job application 2 is created for A1 with apex also

if candidate A1 is placed for java opening job application status of job application 1 will be closed won, job application 2 status should be candidate placed in other job application!!

```
trigger applications on Job_Application__c (after update) {
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        System.debug('trigger initiated');

        Map<Id,Job_Application__c> mapOldJobApps = Trigger.oldMap;
        Map<Id,Job_Application__c> mapNewJobApps = Trigger.newMap;

        Set<Id> setJobAppsIds = new Set<Id>(); 

        for(Job_Application__c jaObj : Trigger.New)
        {
            Job_Application__c oldJobObj = mapOldJobApps.get(jaObj.Id);
            Job_Application__c newJobObj = mapNewJobApps.get(jaObj.Id);
            system.debug('-old job-'+oldJobObj );
            system.debug('-new job-'+NewJobObj );

            if(oldJobObj != null && newJobObj != null && oldJobObj.Status__c != newJobObj.Status__c && newJobObj.Status__c != null && newJobObj.Status__c == 'Closed Won')
            {
                setJobAppsIds.add(jaObj.Id);
                system.debug(+jaObj);
            }

        }
        JobApplicationHandler.afterUpdate(setJobAppsIds);
            System.debug(setJobAppsIds);
    } 
}
```

---

```
public class JobApplicationHandler{public static void afterUpdate(Set<Id> setJobAppsIds){
    if(setJobAppsIds != null && setJobAppsIds.size() > 0) {
        List<Job_Application__c> lstJobApps = [Select Id,Candidate__c,Status__c from Job_Application__c where Id in: setJobAppsIds];
        System.debug('1111111111111111111111111'+lstJobApps);
        if(lstJobApps != null && lstJobApps.size() > 0) {        
            Map<Id,List<Job_Application__c>> mapCandidateIdToListJobApps = new Map<Id,List<Job_Application__c>>();
            for(Job_Application__c ja: lstJobApps) {
                if(!mapCandidateIdToListJobApps.containsKey(ja.Candidate__c)) {
                    mapCandidateIdToListJobApps.put(ja.Candidate__c, new List<Job_Application__c>());
                    system.debug('+++++'+mapCandidateIdToListJobApps);
                }
                mapCandidateIdToListJobApps.get(ja.Candidate__c).add(ja);
                System.debug('+++++++++mapCandidateIdToListJobApps+++++++++'+mapCandidateIdToListJobApps);
            }

            List<Job_Application__c> lstJobAppsUpdate = new List<Job_Application__c>();
            for(Id cndId : mapCandidateIdToListJobApps.keySet()) {
                if(mapCandidateIdToListJobApps.get(cndId) != null && mapCandidateIdToListJobApps.get(cndId).size() > 0) {
                    for(Job_Application__c ja : mapCandidateIdToListJobApps.get(cndId)) {
                        if(ja.Status__c != 'Closed Won') {
                            Job_Application__c jaObj = new Job_Application__c(Id=ja.Id);
                                jaObj.Status__c = 'Offer Rejected by Candidate';
                                System.debug('-----debug----'+jaObj.Status__c);
                                lstJobAppsUpdate.add(jaObj);
                                System.debug('=====debug===='+lstJobAppsUpdate);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(lstJobAppsUpdate != null && lstJobAppsUpdate.size() > 0) {
                    update lstJobAppsUpdate;
                }     
            }     
        } 
    }
}
```

i have no errors in the above code but still its not working

Comment: job application contains 2 lookup-candidate & Job openings. You are creating Job application Manually. write a trigger on Job application and check cnandidate is already placed if so make that application closed won & make other status should be already placed.   here you need play with candidate recordId

Comment: If you created candidate will you create jobappln through code? or manually?

Comment: through manually only

Comment: Please note that use of redundant punctuation (e.g. `???`, `!!!`, etc.) is often considered rude.

Comment: If you keep adding duplicate punctuation in your comments, I will flag them as rude. Please do not continue to use duplicative punctuation in your posts.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Job_Application__c> lstJobApps = [
    Select Id,Candidate__c,Status__c 
    from Job_Application__c 
    where Id in: setJobAppsIds
];
```

This query is your issue. `setJobAppsIds` is created in your trigger as the set of Job Applications that have been updated to Closed Won. Here, you re-query those same records.

When your trigger processes these records, it makes no changes. It does not have the records it needs to change, which are the other Job Applications associated with the Candidates, because those other Job Applications are not being queried.

Instead of querying this way (which actually just wastes time and limits, because it pulls in data your code already has), you need to accumulate a `Set<Id>` of *candidate Ids* for the Candidates associated to these Job Applications.

Then, you'd query for all the Job Applications for those Candidates that did not just get updated to Closed Won, and update them all to the status you need. This can actually simplify your logic quite a bit, as I don't believe you'll need a `Map<Id,List<Job_Application__c>>` at all. Instead, you'd just query

```
List<Job_Application__c> lstJobApps = [
    SELECT Id 
    FROM Job_Application__c 
    WHERE Id NOT IN :setJobAppsIds AND Candidate__c IN :setCandidateIds AND Status__c = 'Open'
]; // or whatever Statuses you want to update.
```

Then, iterate over those records and set each one's `Status__c` to your new value, and update the list

```
update lstJobApps;
```

Simple, and no need to create a new list of objects or use other collections.

If you structure your logic effectively, as you already do in the code you posted in your question, your trigger is already recursion-proof, because you take action only upon records that need to be updated.

Comment: What would you like me to clarify? I've already included some code examples in my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am not able to write the code for you. That's not what we do here at SFSE. I am happy to provide more description of any point that's not clear.

Comment: if I'm not wrong my trigger is correct right??i need to update only the handler??

Comment: Yes, I think your trigger looks fine. You do not need the `null` checks in your `if` statement (those values will never be `null`), but the code is fine and I believe it will work.

Comment: That was just meant as an example. You should write whatever `Status__c` filter you need for your requirements.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you, @Myxidoa. I'm trying to be as clear as I can, but you've got to be able to take up an answer or suggestion and implement it yourself. If you encounter more errors, do your best to debug them or at least identify a single, specific issue that you can ask about.

Comment: List<Job_Application__c> lstJobApps = [SELECT Id,status__c,candidate__c FROM Job_Application__c WHERE Id NOT IN :setJobAppsIds And candidate__c IN :setJobAppsIds];
System.debug('1111111111111111111111111'+lstJobApps);                                this where i get   an error