# recursive trigger on junction object

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I'm getting an error while updating status how to avoid it

```
trigger applications on Job_Application__c (after update)
{
    set<id> candiadteIds = new set<id>();
    List<Job_Application__c> JbApplist = new List<Job_Application__c>();

    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate)
    {

        for(Job_Application__c jaObj : Trigger.New)
        {          
            candiadteIds.add(jaObj.candidate__c);   
        }
        List<Job_Application__c> jbList =[select id,candidate__c,status__c from Job_Application__c where candidate__c in:candiadteIds and id Not IN :trigger.new];

        for(Job_Application__c up : jbList)
        {
            if(up.status__c != 'Closed Won')
            {
                up.Status__c = 'Already Placed';
                JbApplist.add(up);
                system.debug(JbApplist);
            }
        }
    }
    if(!JbApplist.isEmpty())
    {
        update JbApplist;     
    }
}
```

> Error
>   Job_Application trigger event AfterUpdate
>   Job_Application trigger event AfterUpdate
>   Job_Application trigger event AfterUpdate
>   Job_Application trigger event AfterUpdate
>   Job_Application trigger event AfterUpdate
>   Job_Application trigger event AfterUpdate
>   Job_Application trigger event AfterUpdate
>   Job_Application trigger event AfterUpdate: []
>   Trigger.applications: line 27, column 1

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Generally speaking, when you encounter an error, it really helps if you include the full text of the error message along with the stack trace. Including your code, as you have already done, is always a good idea too. One way to improve your question here would be to tell us what research you've already done to try to resolve your issue, and any other approaches that you've tried. You can add additional information to your question by making an [edit].

Comment: This does *not* do what you said you were aiming to do in the [previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244624/trigger-to-update-related-records-on-junction-object). Your logic will now cause all other Job Application records to be marked 'Already Placed' when *any* update is made.

Answer (score 1):

The most effective defense against recursive trigger operation is to ensure that your logic only is fired when you observe that changes need to be made. In your [previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244624/trigger-to-update-related-records-on-junction-object), you had already established such a structure:

```
        if(oldJobObj != null && newJobObj != null && oldJobObj.Status__c != newJobObj.Status__c && newJobObj.Status__c != null && newJobObj.Status__c == 'Closed Won') {
            setJobAppsIds.add(jaObj.Id);
        }
    }
    JobApplicationHandler.afterUpdate(setJobAppsIds);
```

Here, you checked each inbound record to see if a change had been made that required your code to do work - to update other Job Applications. Then, you called your handler class only with the Ids of the records that had qualifying changes.

This code is already proof against most recursion issues, because other updates made by your code - to set other Job Applications to 'Already Placed' - won't result in your trigger executing again.

The logic in your new version is vulnerable to an endless loop of recursion, and does not appear to implement what you said you were planning to do. Instead, you update all Job Applications related to a Candidate who had an Application updated to fire the trigger. Since your new version doesn't check, like the first version did, whether it actually needs to take action based on the updates that are made, it's vulnerable to infinite recursion.

You were already on the right track - I would go back to your earlier code.